# Avoiding the review queue in a hold/close question, having an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions, unanswered-questions, on-hold

Pretty straight forward, I can answer a question which was tagged as unclear and put on hold. What should I do?

The question mentioned is [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67531/filling-in-gaps-in-a-grid) one. Essentially, what the OP asks is help on an algorithm that fills any empty space (`O`) that has at least two adjacent `1` values.

I understand very clearly the need to put unclear questions on hold but it is disturbing when you understood the question and think you have a valid answer to give, but you can't because it's on hold...

Comment: If you understood the question, did you edit it to clarify it to everyone else? If not, why not?

Comment: Because the question is in my sense quite clear but i do not see how to simplify without answering it. and i understand i should not answer in the edition of the question

This is the question : [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67531/filling-in-gaps-in-a-grid)

Comment: can answer or can't answer?

Comment: I have the answer but I am unable to because question is on hold :D

Comment: After reading the examples, I do think it is clear that the OP wants to change 0 to 1 if any 2 neighboring cells are 1... I think the OP just boggled the vocabulary.

Comment: I do too and an answer could be given it is pretty cumbersome to have to wait for the question to be re-reviewed to allow answering

Comment: As I search this migh be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions . It describes the how-to to reopen a question. However, as you stated, this doesn't prevent the re-review queue... the easiest/quickest would be to call a moderator, but that isn't granted.

Comment: I tried that but the absence of intrusive chat system (which i totally approve, chat is sooo annoying...) prevents from contacting moderator and in particular the one whom held the question if you know another way i'd take it

Comment: flag for moderator support and explain the situation. But moderators have better things to do with their time.

Comment: well right i'll try an edit and try to unlock answering

Comment: Not really, i understand quite clearly what is a closed or on-hold question, but i was wondering how to push the process of resolution faster if an answer could be given but answering was blocked

Finally i understood that the best way to avoid the procedure is to follow the procedure :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to edit the question; others have already commented in that question why it's unclear to them.

Take the time to edit the clarifying details in the question:

- it gets re-opened
- you get to answer
- The OP gets their question answered
- You get reputation
- EVERYBODY WINS